# django pre and next page

Tags: python, django

I used django work a news site.
How to obtain a classification of an article in the previous and next article.
Like Blog's page.But the type's ID is not continuous in **mysql**.

like:

```
   <a href="url_pre">pre</a>
   <a href="url_next">next</a>
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/pagination/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is typically achieved using `get_next_by_FOO()` functionality which is [documented here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.7/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_next_by_FOO).

In your model you need a date or datetime field:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    date_published = models.DateTimeField()
```

And in your views you can then fetch next/previous item:

```
    next_post = article.get_next_by_date_published()
    prev_post = article.get_previous_by_date_published()
```

Comment: It's in django for quite a while - 1.5 and 1.6 have it as well (https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.5/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_next_by_FOO)